# i need to right angle the vertexes draw it by hand

Tags: mesh

[image]i draw with hand this model and the right angles are not at 90 degrees. how can be this corrected? thanks.[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV17C.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can select two (or more) vertices of an horizontal line and press <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, and <kbd>Enter</kbd> (scale their Y value by 0). The same with vertical lines (<kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

If the editing plane isn't aligned to the global axis, first change the *Transform Orientation* to *Normal* and make sure that you're selecting the appropriate axis accordingly.

Note that perspective views can cause right angles to not look not straight. You can use the measure tool to check the angle. Just drag out a straight line using vertex snapping then click and drag from the middle of the measuring line to check the angle.

Comment: Maybe mention the pivot?

Comment: TRANSFORMATION ORIENTATION TO NORMAL is doing so triangle shape. TO GLOBAL is good to me.